# Decision planned for 11 April

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

> We are 1 of the 2 final vendors left. Presentation to Company A has
> been delivered. **Decision planned for 11 April**.

**Decision planned for 11 April** - What I want to say is the decision will be out on **11 April** on whether we are selected as the vendors, but to make it concise and professional. Nevertheless, is that grammatical and idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

What you're saying will probably make sense with the context of the message but it creates ambiguity about who is making the decision and what exactly will be done on 11 April.

To be more clear I'd suggest saying something like: **We will have their decision by 11 April.**

This tells the reader that the decision refers to Company A choosing a vendor and they will be telling you what they've decided on 11 April.